# Why is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

I don't understand why the last two sums equal the $exp(iz)$.I tried changing the limit of
$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$ by leting $2y=2n+1$ so that i get $\sum_{0=1/2}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2y}}{(2y)!}$ but the lower limit doesn't equal $0$ so i can't add them.
The aim was to get $y=0$ so that i get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!} +\sum_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2y}}{(2y)!}$$ so that i can change y to n and have $2 exp(iz)$ which was closer to the desired result but i just don't see how $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^2n}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2y)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(iz)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: $2n$ is even, $2n+1$ is odd.

Comment: The answer is in the title ! Think about even/odd terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that in the second to last line you are adding two sums: one involving even exponents/factorial arguments and the other involving the odd ones. Thus, when adding both sums you end up with all natural exponents/factorial arguments. Try writing the first few terms of both sums and reordering them to convince yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You have
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!}=1+0+\frac{(iz)^2}{2!}+0+\frac{(iz)^4}{4!}+\cdots
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=0+iz+0+\frac{(iz)^3}{3!}+\cdots
$$
So,
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^{2n}}{(2n)!}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(iz)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}&=1+iz+\frac{(iz)^2}{2!}+\frac{(iz)^3}{3!}+\frac{(iz)^4}{4!}+\cdots\\
&=\exp(iz).
\end{align}